# How to create a sequential list of filenames in R

Tags: r

I did a bibliometric analisys in R, using the Bibliometrix package. To start everything we need to use the readFiles command, which worked fine for me listing every file I needed. Something like this:

```
readFiles("file (1).txt", "file (2).txt", "file (3).txt")
```

Since we are talking about dozens of files for each analysis, I´ve tried to improve the code for future studies, doing something like:

```
FileName <- "UniversityA"
NumberofFiles <- 80
Files <- paste0(FileName, " (", seq(1:NumberofFiles),").txt", collapse='","')
readFiles(Files)
```

The idea is that "Files" would store a list like "UniversityA (1).txt", "UniversityA (2).txt, etc. With that, I could only change the name of the university in the analysis, and provide the total number of files to import the data. The problem is, when I try to read the list created, I get an error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : could not open connection.
```

I know that the problem is in the way the different elements are combined, since it works fine if I use a single file. I´ve tried many combinations on the collapse option, but all with the same problem, like:

```
collapse = '","'
collapse = "\",\""
```

Can anyone think of a solution?

Thanks,

André

Comment: why not use `list.files()` function, it even has an argument `pattern`

Comment: For what I understand of function `bibliometrix::readFiles` you don't need `collapse`, just run the `paste` command without it.

Comment: let R do the work to get filenames, if they already exist? if you are in the proper directory, then try `filePaths = dir(getwd(), pattern = "*.txt", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)`. otherwise specify the directory

Comment: Actually, all of the options above generate the same error. They all retrieve the file names, but in a way that the readFiles function is not able to read. I was trying to play with collapse options to see if I could get something like: "filename1.txt","filename2.txt", etc. It seems that the function only works with quotes and commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to expand a vector into different parameters in a base R function, you need to use `do.call()`. For example

```
FileName <- "UniversityA"
NumberofFiles <- 80
Files <- paste0(FileName, " (", seq(1:NumberofFiles), ").txt")
do.call("readFiles", as.list(Files))
```

Note that `Files` is a proper 80-element vector here and has not been collapsed.

Comment: It has almost worked. The way it is, it got me the same error, but then I mixed your code with Matt's suggestion, and got it working, like this: 
    filePaths = dir(getwd(), pattern = "*.txt", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
    String <- do.call("readFiles", as.list(filePaths))
    WoSdata <- convert2df(String, dbsource="isi", format="plaintext")